# Who decides how consumer electronics should be labeled and advertised?

Tags: international, consumer-protection

Let's suppose I'm a citizen who is very dissatisfied with misleading digital storage drive capacity labeling, where manufacturers use fake `GB` (base-10 SI metric decimal `giga` unit prefix equals to 1000 in power of 3) instead of correct (in context of computing and computer science) base-2 binary scale units (e.g. `GiB` with prefix `gibi` equals to 1024 in power of 3).

Aforementioned means that instead of expected **64** **binary** `GB` I could get **64** **decimal** `GB` which is around **59** **binary** `GB`.

Hence the questions:

- Who decides how those products could be labeled?
- If I would like to put an end on this misleading practice, who should I ask for help?
- To whom should a possible petition for more correct labeling be addressed to?

The context is international market, I suppose, but also could be local.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about identifying ***political** bodies responsible for law **creation***, not the law or legal process or the legal professions.

Comment: @Nij so it's for Politics stack then? Where ask it if not here?

Comment: Voted to close as essentially a duplicate of https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7920/why-are-manufacturers-allowed-to-make-false-claims-about-memory-capacity-of-thum/. In the context the international standard is that GB is gigabyte is 1000 to the power of 3. The questioner's understanding is not in line with the international standard (that has existed since the late 90s IIRC, although the accepted answer cites a standard published in 2008).

Comment: 1GB = 1 billion bytes. The whole premise of the question is deeply flawed and based on a refusal to accept that someone’s knowledge is outdated.

Comment: It's interesting that you **give the answer in your question**. 1GB ~= 1GiB, either in name or value. A person who knew nothing about mathematics or computers could at least assume that GB and GiB are not the same thing.